# fine uploader changing the input name to match what my script is expecting

Tags: fine-uploader

I am incorporating Fine Uploader into a form that already exists.

I've added three Fine Uploader file upload fields.  I have one script that controls all three of the boxes.  I looked at the inputName attribute and attempted to change that, but it changed the name of all of the fine upload fields to what i set as the inputName (in this case it was photo1).  That's not exactly what i want.  I want to set the inputName for each field to something different.

In my case, it is important that I have 3 individual boxes because I have a message box that goes with each photo.

I mainly just want to use Fine Uploader for its ability to allow iphone users to select a photo if they are on the phone and also for the thumbnail preview after the photo is selected.  All that stuff is great.

The rest of the form I have is already functioning and I can submit it using standard input file fields.

Questions:

1. Is there a way to use multiple fields on a single page? Do I need to
   write a seperate $('#photo1').fineUploader(){...}); per input box?
2. Is there a way to change the input name for each file upload field?
3. I assume i can achieve this with seperate script blocks, but is
   there a better/cleaner than repeating all that code?
4. I downloaded the PHP Server Handler files and when i submit my test form with interceptSubmit: true, I see the images upload to my server.  That works. (i kinda made a simple form just to test it out).  When i change to interceptSubmit: false, add a page called thankyou_post.php as my post action page and in that page I'm just seeing what the form is sending by print_r($_POST); and all i get is Array ( [submit] => submit ) as the response.

I suppose my next step will be to try to write custom blocks per file field and see if the form can process that better.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#photo1, #photo2, #photo3').fineUploader({
            debug: true,
            template: "qq-dav-photo-with-thumb",
            thumbnails: {
          placeholders: {
            waitingPath: "placeholders/waiting-generic.png",
            notAvailablePath: "placeholders/not_available-generic.png"
          }
      },
            form: {
                interceptSubmit: false
            },
            camera: {
                ios: true
            },
      request: {
        endpoint: 'thankyou.php',
                paramsInBody: true,
                inputName: 'photo1'
      },
            messages: {
                emptyError: 'File is empty',
                noFilesError: 'No files attached.',
                onLeave: 'We are still uploading your files...Please wait.'
            },
            validation: {
                allowedExtensions: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'gif', 'png'],
                itemLimit: 3,
                stopOnFirstInvalidFile: true
            }
    }).on('progress', function (id, fileName, uploadedBytes, totalBytes) {

            console.log('progress...');

}).on('complete', function(event, id, fileName, responseJSON) {
    if (responseJSON.success){

        file_name = responseJSON.name;
        console.log('hoorah! File name: '+file_name);
    };
}).on('allComplete', function(event, id, fileName, responseJSON) {
        console.log('hoorah! All complete!');
});

  });
```

Any thoughts on what i can do to make this work?

**UPDATE #1**
LINK: http://ijwebsites.com/fineuploader/

This is the HTML on my form page.

```
<form action="thankyou_post.php" method="post"
id="qq-form" name="webform" enctype="multipart/form-data" >

<!-- Fine Uploader DOM Element
====================================================================== -->
<div id="photo1"></div>

<br>
<br>

<div id="photo2"></div>

<br>
<br>

<div id="photo3"></div>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">

</form>
```

And my thankyou_post.php page for my test page is very basic, i just want it to tell what values were submitted to the page so i am doing on that page:

```
<?php
if ($_FILES["photo1"]["error"] > 0) {
  echo "Error: " . $_FILES["photo1"]["error"] . "<br>";
} else {
  echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["photo1"]["name"] . "<br>";
  echo "Type: " . $_FILES["photo1"]["type"] . "<br>";
  echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["photo1"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
  echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["photo1"]["tmp_name"];
}
?>
```

When I submit the form, i get a message "Error: 4".  What do you think the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to have multiple uploaders on the same page, and have varying options for each uploader (in this case, a differing [`request.inputName` option](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/options.html#request.inputName)), you'll need to initialize each instance separately.  You can combine initialization into a common function that takes the input name as a parameter, if you'd like.

If you want Fine Uploader to send the entire contents of your form, including the selected files, ensure the `form.interceptSubmit` option is set to `true` (this is the default anyway).  If you do not want this to happen, and you want to upload selected files in a separate request, then you should not enable form support at all in Fine Uploader.  Form support was created for those who want Fine Uploader to completely manage a form.

It's not clear from your question what your form or forms look like, as you have left out your markup.  If you are expecting Fine Uploader to control multiple file input elements in a single form, then you will need to make use of the [`extraButtons` option](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/options.html#extraButtons).

Comment: thanks ray. It is a single form. I'd say my form is mostly pretty basic.  There are fields like first name, last name, email address, three message fields, three photo upload fields and a checkbox.  I even simplified my example even more by removing all of the fields except the photo fields (for testing purposes).  I think what i want is when i click the submit button is submits the form as if it were a standard form and then my script will handle all of the $_POST processes.  So, i should set form.interceptSubmit to FALSE.  can it work that way?  I seem to have an issue with the POST.

Comment: Sounds pretty complex, actually.  Why do you need 3 upload fields?  Just use one.  My answer covers when to use interceptSubmit, how to deal with multiple buttons, etc.  If you insist on multiple buttons, it doesn't seem like multiple uploader instances is the right approach.  Sounds like you should be using one uploader instance but that attaches the other 2 buttons via the extraButtons option.  The docs page for these options and the associated feature pages should give you more detail.

Comment: yeah the reason for multiple image fields is because there is a message box that goes with the image.  And so we want the user to have a field where they select an image and then write a description about that image.  Yes, i suppose it is pretty complex.  I'm glad to hear you say that because I was hoping that this was going to be just plug it into the page and then be able to submit form with standard method post to a script like i would normally do.  I did try the extraButtons options before, but i didnt have any luck with that.  Did you happen to see my example link?

Comment: oh yeah and about using the extraButtons options.  I think i decided not to use the extraButtons options because i didnt see a place where i could set the inputFilename for each of the fields and thats what i was trying to do.

Comment: Looks like there isn't a way to set the `inputName` for extraButtons, as you have observed.  That can be added though.  Open up a feature request and we can prioritize it for the next planned release.  Your situation is solved easily by Fine Uploader's form support via `extraButtons`, except for the custom `inputName` requirement.

Comment: Just opened up this feature request myself: https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/1312

Comment: one other question i have for you is IF i set "form.interceptSubmit" to false and then submit the form, I'm not getting anything in the $_POST fields.  So where are the values for the image fields in my form?  They seem to all be empty.  That is where i am stuck.  I've even tried submitting the form to the PHP Server to handle the photos changing the inputName to match the names i entered in my script.  They come through as blanks.

Comment: If you set that option to false, Fine Uploader will not send files with the form submit.  So, if you do want the files to be sent as part of the submit automatically, you must not change the default value of this option (it must be set to true, which is the default).

Comment: oh. doh!  I was think that was just disabling the ajax form submission not everything.  Ok.  Sounds like i'm understanding this better. thanks!